# SailsJS ReferenceError: Model is not defined when running WebStorm Node debug mode

Tags: node.js, sails.js, webstorm

I'm relatively new to SailsJS and what I'm trying to do here is to run functions on debug mode so I can gain some time when working on backend scripts (compared to rerun each request on Postman after each modification on a script..).

This is the script for a route I'm trying to run in debug mode:

```
module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'Upsert',

  description: 'Upsert a vehicle recovery.',

  inputs: {
     ...
  },

  exits: {
     ...
  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    try{
      //Set vehicle recovery if an Id is present
      let existingVehicleRecovery = {};
      if (inputs.id) {
        existingVehicleRecovery = await VehicleRecovery.findOne({ id: inputs.id }).populate('bodyworkPrices').populate('maintenancePrices').populate('additionalCostsList');

 
      if (inputs.id) {
        return exits.updateSuccess({ vehicleRecovery, dependentValues, exceptions });
      } else {
        return exits.createSuccess({ vehicleRecovery, dependentValues, exceptions });
      }

    } catch(e){
      console.log('Error: ',e);
    }
  }
};

const inputs = {
  'opportunityId':'0065E00000OYgK9QAL',
  'plateNumber': 'AQ828TW',
  'id': 613
};

module.exports.fn(inputs);
```

And this is the error that pops up when I'm trying to run this function:

[image]

For some reason, the `VehicleRecovery` model is not recognized by node here.

The server is running locally in parallels.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the solution. This is what your configuration should look like if you want to debug a SailsJS or any Node.js api:

[image]

In the javascript file section, I chose nodemon but you might select node or sails as well. After this you need to run your configuration in Run mode or debug mode.

[image]

And each time you send a request via Postman or the browser, webstorm will be available to read the variables for each script run (you will see something like in the screenshot below).

[image]